# How can I wait for announcement to complete before moving focus to some element?

Tags: ios, swift, uiaccessibility

I have a scenario where I want to make an announcement before I move the focus to some different elements. When I try to do it-

```
UIAccessibility.post(notification: .announcement, argument: "a very very very long text")

UIAccessibility.post(notification: .layoutChanged, argument: headerResult)
```

For the above code, my focus moves to the headerResult without completing the announcement.
I want to keep both notifications independent of each other.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can listen to the `announcementDidFinish` notification (see [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiaccessibility/1620202-announcementdidfinishnotificatio)) and check the user dictionary to compare the value for the `announcementStringValueUserInfoKey` key with your "a very very ..." String so you know which announcement finished. But note that it's very confusing for visually impaired persons if focus moves without their interaction (especially if it happens after a long text announcement). You should check the value for `announcementWasSuccessfulUserInfoKey` to only move focus if the announcement was read successfully until the end.